# Whenever I write an apostrophe it inputs two instead of one (same with quotes). How do I fix it?

Tags: keyboard, input-languages

So right now whenever I choose my language for english It's "United States - International" and when I'm on this one whenver I write a quote (") it actually writes 2 at once and I have to go back to write inbetween which I just can't get used to. Laso when I type in an apostrophe it again types 2 at once and I have to go back. Which language do I have to choose to fix that while every other button key stays the same when pressing shift? I tried English - United Kingdom, but that makes my quotes shift+2 and my at sight shift + ' button. Please help :/ Does it have to do with that I have set my location to Bulgaria in the control panel (Win7)?

Answer (score 7):

This is a feature of the "international" part of "US-international", so that you can write accents (first type the character that looks like the accent you want to have and then the letter). For a single quote hit the quote and then a space.

Otherwise just use the non-international version of the US keyboard.